# Can't get _id mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Good afternoon, just started studying node.js and ran into one problem. When I try to get _id, nothing is transmitted (does not get into the link), I tried a bunch of ways on the internet, so far I stopped at this method:
Changed _id from objectId to string using uuidv4 ():

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose')
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

const course = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    img: String,
    _id: { type: String, default: uuidv4() }
})

module.exports = model('Course', course)
```

But the _id itself is still not passed to the link. But when I enter the ID myself, then everything works as I wanted:

```
const { Router } = require('express')
const Course = require('../models/course')
const router = Router()
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const courses = await Course.find().lean()
    res.render('courses', {
        title: 'Курсы',
        isCourses: true,
        courses
    })
})

router.get('/:id/edit', async (req, res) => {
    if (!req.query.allow) {
        return res.redirect('/')
    }
    const id = req.params.id
    const course = await Course.findById({ _id: id }).lean()
    res.render('course-edit', {
        title: `${course.title}`,
        course
    })
})

router.post('/edit', async (req, res) => {
    await Course.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.id, req.body).lean()
    res.redirect('/courses')
})

router.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id
    const course = await Course.findById({ _id: id }).lean()
    res.render('course', {
        layout: 'empty',
        title: `${course.title}`,
        course
    })
})

module.exports = router
```

When I try to get _id myself it gives this error

```
title: `${course.title}`,
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null
```

How can I display _id in a string in a link?

Answer (score 0):

[findById](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById) is not taking an object, you just need to pass the id directly to `findById`

```
const course = await Course.findById(id).lean()
```

or you can use `findOne` instead

```
const course = await Course.fineOne({ _id: id }).lean()
```

Comment: unfortunately, he still does not see the ID and does not insert it into the link 
`
 title: `${course.title}`,
                         ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null
`

Comment: could you try to console.log the `req.params.id` and show the result here?

Comment: `
router.get('/:id/edit', async (req, res) => {
    if (!req.query.allow) {
        return res.redirect('/')
    }
    const id = req.params.id
    const course = await Course.findOne({ _id: id }).lean()
    console.log(id);
    res.render('course-edit', {
        title: `${course.title}`,
        course
    })
})
`
Output - edit

Comment: what is the result of `console.log(req.params.id)` in your server logs?

Comment: could you provide how did you call this request?

Comment: console.log(req.params.id)

Comment: sorry, I meant how did you call the request router.get('/:id/edit, ...)?

Comment: You meant this 

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use('/', homeRoutes)
app.use('/card', cardRoutes)
app.use('/add', addRoutes)
app.use('/courses', coursesRoutes)